# How Can I configure DHCPv6

Tags: cisco, router, ipv6, dhcp, dhcpv6

I want to config one DHCPv6 server using Packet Tracer and with multiple routers, the router takes IP addresses from a server and distribute to computers .I have done that with IPv4 using IP helper but in IPv6 there is no Ip helper
[image]

I created in local pool but it did not  work  .

Can you help me to understand .
[image]

Comment: There's a lot of great guides, that covers the IPv4 vs IPv6 design in regards to DHCP helper. A few: [https://supportforums.cisco.com/t5/network-infrastructure-documents/stateful-dhcpv6-relay-configuration-example/ta-p/3149338](https://supportforums.cisco.com/t5/network-infrastructure-documents/stateful-dhcpv6-relay-configuration-example/ta-p/3149338) and [http://packetpushers.net/ipv4-dhcp-vs-ipv6-dhcpv6/](http://packetpushers.net/ipv4-dhcp-vs-ipv6-dhcpv6/)

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options

- To set up a DHCP relay agent (as stated by Ron Maupin
- To set a IPv6 pool in your Cisco router

#### DHCP relay agent

> > **enable**
>
> # **config term**
>
> (config)# **interface [interface-1]**
>
> (config-if)# **ipv6 dhcp destination [destination ipv6 address] [interface-2]**
>
> (config-if)# **end**

Where *interface-1* is the interface which will be set with the DHCPv6 address and *interface-2* is the interface which will be acting as the relay.

Remember that, in order for this to work, the address set for your relaying interface has to be routable.

In order to see the information of the received address:

> > # show ipv6 dhcp interface

#### Stateful configuration by Cisco Routers

> (config)# ipv6 unicast-routing
>
> (config)# **ipv6 dhcp pool [pool name]**
>
> (config)# **addreess prefix [IPV6 \64] lifetime infinite inifinite**
>
> (config)# **dns-server [ipv6 address of DNS Server]**
>
> (config)# **domain-name [mydomain.org]**

To assign an interface to the pool:

> (config-if)# **ipv6 dhcp server [pool name]**
>
> (conifg-if)# **ipv6 enable [mode]-commit**

Where *mode* may be either *rapid* or *normal* commit. An example of the prefix may be 2010:BB:BB:11::/64.

More information at:

- [IP Addressing: DHCP Configuration Guide, Cisco IOS Release 15M&T](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/ipaddr_dhcp/configuration/15-mt/dhcp-15-mt-book/ip6-dhcp-rel-agent.html)
- [IPv6 Implementation Guide - Implementing DHCP for IPv6](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/ipv6/configuration/15-2mt/ipv6-15-2mt-book/ip6-dhcp.html#GUID-DEFAE91A-5352-400C-9EFB-F41A159EA12F)

Comment: Note: Assuming from your Network Map that the Server is actually a DHCP Server, I would daisy chain Switch 7 to Router 4 as DHCP Relay Agent, and then Router 4 to Router 3) and finally Router 3 to your Server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the `ipv6 dhcp relay destination` interface command. There are also multiple options for your RAs (Router Advertisements) that you should investigate. Cisco maintains documents, e.g. [*Implementing DHCP for IPv6*](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/ipv6/configuration/15-2mt/ipv6-15-2mt-book/ip6-dhcp.html#GUID-DB359FCB-5AEB-44AD-B2BD-3527A2148872), about the large IPv6 addressing subject. You have more options with IPv6, including prefix delegation to your routers.

> ### Configuring the DHCPv6 Relay Agent
>
> **SUMMARY STEPS**
>
> 1. **enable**
> 2. **configure terminal**
> 3. **interface** *type number*
> 4. **ipv6 dhcp relay destination** *ipv6-address* [*interface-type interface-number*]
> 5. **end**

Comment: ipv6 dhcp relay destination cammand unrecognize in a router and  I do not want router to be as server .

Comment: That _is_ a router command. You are probably running into a Packet Tracer limitation, which is limited to CCNA subjects, and this is not one of those. You will need to use something more, e.g. GNS, to really configure this.

Comment: yeah I am using packet tracer so shoud I use GNS to configure this .?

Comment: Use something that gives you the full router configuration commands. Packet Tracer is fairly limited. If you want to explore subjects beyond CCNA, then you should use something else.

Comment: Really I dont know I working on project actually  for IPv4 I did it but in IPv6 is more difficult I show the picture there are many option in DHCPv6 can you help me  just at this point ? using packet tracer .

Comment: I answered your question about how to configure a DHCP relay for IPv6 (the `ip helper-address` command is a DHCP relay), and you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer, even though Packet Tracer doesn't support it. The whole subject of IPv6 address assignment is far too large to discuss on this site. Even DHCP configuration is too broad (see the document I linked in my answer). If you have another question, then you should start a new question, but you need to be specific. A question that is too broad will be closed as too broad.