# Why command "ipv6 dhcp relay" doesn't work at packet tracer?

Tags: routing, router, ipv6, packet-tracer, dhcpv6

I'm trying to enable dhcp for ipv6 with the "**ipv6 dhcp relay dest**" command but, I'm receiving an error and I'm trying both of these commands but none work.

***Router model:*** 2811

```
(config)# interface [interface-1]

(config-if)# ipv6 dhcp destination [destination ipv6 address]
[interface-2]
```

and

> interface type number
>
> ipv6 dhcp relay destination ipv6-address [interface-type interface-number]

Error:

> % Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

[Source](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46440/how-can-i-configure-dhcpv6)

Comment: What IOS version are you using?

Comment: Huh.... `Cisco IOS Software, 2800 Software (C2800NM-ADVIPSERVICESK9-M), Version 12.4(15)T1, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2811 router is fairly old and End-of-Life since 2016, with the last software updates in 2014 (over four years ago). Your IOS version probably does not support this command. You always need to look at the IOS versions where the command was introduced:

[*Cisco IOS IPv6 Command Reference - ipv6 dhcp relay destination*](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/ipv6/command/ipv6-cr-book/ipv6-i1.html#wp4145512431)

[image]

---

Also, this does not seem like a CCNA-level subject, and it may not be supported by Packet Tracer, which is an emulator that is limited in what it supports. A real 2811 may be able to run the correct IOS version (or it may not even be available for that EoS router).

Answer (score 2):

It's an old question - but for anyone finding it you should know that the IPv6 relay agent has not been implemented in Packet Tracer for **ANY** router.